# pipes spawning too fast in flappy bird pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, flappy-bird-clone

Im working on this flappy bird pygame tutorial and when I tested the code the  pipes spawned in too fast. I'm using a tutorial since I'm fairly new to python and would appreciate any help. Thanks. Here is the link to the tutorial website: https://github.com/clear-code-      projects/FlappyBird_Python/blob/master/flappy.py

Here is the code I have so far.

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
from random import randint


def draw_floor():
    screen.blit(floor_surface,(floor_x_pos,750))
    screen.blit(floor_surface,(floor_x_pos + 576,750))


def create_pipe():
    new_pipe = pipe_surface.get_rect(midtop = (288,375))
    return new_pipe

def move_pipes(pipes):
    for pipe in pipes:
        pipe.centerx -= 5
    return pipes

def draw_pipes(pipes):
    for pipe in pipes:
        if pipe.bottom >= 750:
            screen.blit(pipe_surface,pipe)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((576,855))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Game variables
gravity = 0.25
bird_movement = 0

bg_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs','bg.png')).convert_alpha())

floor_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs','base.png')).convert_alpha())
floor_x_pos = 0

bird_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs','bird2.png')).convert_alpha())
bird_rect = bird_surface.get_rect(center = (100,427))


pipe_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs','pipe.png')))
pipe_list = []
SPAWNPIPE = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWNPIPE,5000)
pipe_height = [300,500,700]

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bird_movement = 0
                bird_movement -= 12

    if event.type == SPAWNPIPE:
        pipe_list.extend(create_pipe())
        
            
    # bird
    screen.blit(bg_surface,(0,0))

    bird_movement += gravity
    bird_rect.centery += int(bird_movement)
    screen.blit(bird_surface,bird_rect)

    # pipes
    pipe_list = move_pipes(pipe_list)
    draw_pipes(pipe_list)

    
    floor_x_pos -= 1
    draw_floor()
    if floor_x_pos <= -576:
        floor_x_pos = 0


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)`
```

Comment: try add an sleep at the end of your code, sleep(50)

Answer (score 2):

Indent the SPAWNPIPE check:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bird_movement = 0
                bird_movement -= 12

        if event.type == SPAWNPIPE:    # indent this
             pipe_list.extend(create_pipe())
```

Comment: thank you alot. This is my first stack overflow question and how u guys helped me so quick makes me want to use stack overflow more. thanks

Comment: Please accept an answer so this post is removed from the "No Answer" list. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that once you get the first `SPAWNPIPE` event, the `event.type` condition for adding a new pipe becomes True.

However, due to improper indentation, that condition is repeatedly checked *every frame* until the next event is received.  This means the code is continually spawning pipes every frame during this time.

Fix the indentation, to bring the pipe-event check back inside the event for-loop:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bird_movement = 0
                bird_movement -= 12

        if event.type == SPAWNPIPE:                        # <<-- HERE  
            pipe_list.extend(create_pipe())                # <<-- AND HERE
```

Which makes the `SPAWNPIPE` check be performed only when the event is actually received.

Comment: thank you this helped me alot. Really appreciate this very much.